# Techniques for serving CSS only to modern browsers

Tags: css

What are some techniques for serving CSS only to modern browsers, and showing plain, unstyled HTML to "old ie"?

Currently using the following, but not terribly excited about my main CSS being within conditional comments.

I'm sure this has been covered before, but I had a hard time searching for it.

```
  <!--[if !(lt IE 9)]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/normalize.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/oldie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to include browser specific CSS files in a HTML page:

1) Using Conditional statements for IE.

2) Using Navigator Object in JavaScript.